# Threading Issue with Turtle Graphics in Python

Tags: python, sockets, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm working on a multiplayer game using Python's Turtle graphics library, and I'm facing issues with threading and character movement synchronisation. Here's the current version of my code:

```
from turtle import *
import time
import threading
import socket
import json


# Define the Character class for managing user characters
class Character:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, username):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.username = username
        self.userTurtle = None
        self.turtle = None

    def createTurtle(self):
        # Create Turtle objects for the character and username label
        self.userTurtle = Turtle()
        self.userTurtle.pencolor('white')
        self.userTurtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.pencolor(self.color)
        self.turtle.fillcolor(self.color)
        self.turtle.shape("square")
    def displayCharacter(self):
        # Update the character's position and username label
        self.turtle.clear()
        self.userTurtle.clear()
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.userTurtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(self.x,self.y)
        self.userTurtle.goto(self.x,self.y-25)
            
        self.userTurtle.write(self.username, move=False, align="center", font=("Cooper Black", 11))

        update()

# Define keyboard functions for character movement     
def rightKey():
    if main.x == 290:
        main.x = -310
    else:
        main.x += 20
    message = json.dumps(["charMov",username,[main.x,main.y]])
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
    main.displayCharacter()
def leftKey():
    if main.x == -310:
        main.x = 290
    else:
        main.x -= 20
    message = json.dumps(["charMov",username,[main.x,main.y]])
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
    main.displayCharacter()
def upKey():
    if main.y != 150:
        main.y += 20
    message = json.dumps(["charMov",username,[main.x,main.y]])
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
    main.displayCharacter()
def downKey():
    if main.y != -130:
        main.y -= 20
    message = json.dumps(["charMov",username,[main.x,main.y]])
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
    main.displayCharacter()



# Function for configuring user settings
def configUser():
    global main, username
    askConfig = input("Do you have a configuration file (file named config.txt) (y/n)? ").lower()
    if askConfig == 'y':
        getConfig = open("config.txt","r").readlines()
        for i in range(len(getConfig)):
            getConfig[i] = getConfig[i].replace('\n','')
    colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple','pink','white','brown','gray','maroon','cyan','antiquewhite','turquoise','mediumpurple']
    colors.sort()
    if askConfig == 'y':
        back = getConfig[0]
    else:
        back = input("Choose a background colour: ").lower()
    while True:
        if back in colors:
            break
        else:
            print("Unavailable background colour!")
            print("Here are all background colours available:")
            for c in colors:
                print(c)
            back = input("Choose a background colour: ").lower()
    if askConfig == 'y':
        username = getConfig[1]
    else:
        username = input("Pick a username: ")
        
        

        
    while True:
        if len(username) < 15 and len(username) > 5:
            client_socket.sendall(json.dumps(['usrRqst',username,back]).encode())
            response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if response == 't':
                break
            else:
                print("Username already exists! Pick another username!")
                username = input("Pick a username: ")

        else:
            print("Invalid Username! Username must be less than 15 characters, and greater than 5 characters.")
            username = input("Pick a username: ")
        
    if askConfig != 'y':
        askSave = input("Would you like to save these values in config.txt (y/n)? ").lower()
        if askSave == 'y':
            save = open("config.txt","w")
            save.write(back+'\n'+username)
            save.close()

    client_socket.sendall(json.dumps(['usrListRqst']).encode())
    loadUsers(json.loads(client_socket.recv(1024).decode()))
    main = Character(back,10,10, username)
    main.createTurtle()
    

# Function for loading other users
def loadUsers(inpDict):
    global userObjectDict
    for c in list(inpDict.keys()):
        if c not in list(userObjectDict.keys()):
            if c != username:
                corr = inpDict[c]
                print(c)
                print(inpDict)
                print(corr)
                userObjectDict[c] = Character(inpDict[c][1],inpDict[c][0][0],inpDict[c][0][1],c)
                userObjectDict[c].createTurtle()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    for n in list(userObjectDict.keys()):
        #if n != username:
        userObjectDict[n].displayCharacter()


def send_message(client_socket):
    while True:
        msg = input()
        message = json.dumps(["msg",msg])
        client_socket.sendall(message.encode())

def receive_messages(client_socket):
    global userObjectDict, username
    print('receive')
    while True:
        try:
            message = json.loads(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
            if not message:
                break
            if message[0] == 'update':
                loadUsers(message[1])
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Connection to the server was reset.")
            break
userObjectDict = dict()

title('Home')
setup(width=650, height=350)
bgcolor("black")
screen = Screen()


width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

tracer(0)




onkey(rightKey,'Right')
onkey(leftKey,'Left')
onkey(upKey,'Up')
onkey(downKey,'Down')
listen()

host = socket.gethostname()

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((host,5087))


configUser()

main.displayCharacter()

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(client_socket,))
receive_thread.daemon = True


receive_thread.start()
send_message(client_socket)





screen.mainloop()
```

Specifically, I need help with:

Addressing the threading issue related to displayCharacter().

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (receive_messages):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/Desktop/Turtle/main.py", line 196, in receive_messages
    loadUsers(message[1])
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/Desktop/Turtle/main.py", line 149, in loadUsers
    userObjectDict[n].displayCharacter()
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/Desktop/Turtle/main.py", line 31, in displayCharacter
    self.turtle.clear()
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 2643, in clear
    self._clear()
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 2621, in _clear
    self.screen._delete(item)
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 557, in _delete
    self.cv.delete(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in delete
  File "/Users/anonymousperson/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2879, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Ensuring synchronized character movement for multiplayer functionality.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code modifications to resolve these issues effectively. Thank you in advance!

I tried creating a function to initialise Turtle() objects separately, however, it resulted in the same error.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use threading at all, so how can we possibly help with your threading issues?

Comment: @jasonharper Turtle uses Tkinter to display graphics, and the Tkinter main loop uses threading implicitly. Also, the code certainly *intends to use* threading, as there is `import threading`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't paste the code properly, with the threading included

Comment: the threading is located at the bottom of the code